# Does the composition of a random variable-valued function with itself induce dependence?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

Say I have a probability space $(\mathbb{R}, \Sigma, \mu)$ and a function $f$ of the form $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for any distinct $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ the functions $f(x_1, -)$ and $f(x_2, -)$ are independent random variables over $(\mathbb{R}, \Sigma, \mu)$.

Now let's define the random variables $G$ and $H$ as:
\begin{align}
G(y) = f(f(x_1, y), y) \\
H(y) = f(f(x_2, y), y) \\
\end{align}

Are $G$ and $H$ independent?

Comment: I think the first question to ask is for $g(y) = f(x_1,y)$, what is the distribution of $g$? For only then can we define the distribution of $G(y) = f(f(x_1,y),y)$, and we are interested in whether $$\mathbb P(G(y)\in A, H(y)\in B) = \mathbb P(G(y)\in A)\mathbb P(H(y)\in B)$$ for Borel sets $A$, and $B$.

Comment: For example, if $g(y)=f(x_1,y)=x_1$ with probability one then clearly $G(y)=f(f(x_1,y),y) = f(x_1,y)$, so if $h(y)=f(x_2,y)=x_2$ with probability one then $G$ and $H$ are independent. But in the general case, I think not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. Here is a **counter-example**:

Let $\mu((-\infty, y]) = \int_{-\infty}^y \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} dt$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$ (the Gaussian distribution).

Define $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by 
$$f(x,y)= \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
y &\mbox{ if $x=0$} \\
0  & \mbox{ if $x\neq 0$} 
\end{array}
\right.$$
Then for any distinct real numbers $x_1,x_2$ (distinct meaning $x_1\neq x_2$), at least one of the numbers $x_1,x_2$ must be nonzero. Thus, at least one of the random variables $f(x_1,y)$ and $f(x_2,y)$ must be zero for all outcomes $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Since a constant is always independent of any other random variable, $f(x_1,y)$ and $f(x_2,y)$ must be independent.

However, take $x_1=1,x_2=2$.  Then for all outcomes $y \in \mathbb{R}$ we have 
\begin{align}
G(y)&=f(f(1,y),y) = f(0,y) = y\\
H(y) &=f(f(2,y),y) = f(0,y) = y
\end{align} 
So $G$ and $H$ are the same (Gaussian) random variable and hence they are not independent.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful answer! My understanding is that this relies upon the phenomenon that a constant random variable is independent of itself. If we add the constraint that $f(x, -)$ must be non-constant, does this change the conclusion?

I am happy to post this as a separate question if you prefer.

Comment: Why are you interested in this question? I used constants because that was the only way I could think of an uncountably infinite number of random variables (all on the sample space $[0,1]$) that are pairwise independent. I do not think this is even possible if you impose the "non-constant" assumption (so, I do not think there even exists a system that satisfies your starting assumptions).  See here for a related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877671/why-one-cannot-construct-more-than-countably-many-independent-random-variables

Comment: By "non-constant" I really mean "non-degenerate." I believe I have an argument that, assuming such a function $f(x,y)$ exists to satisfy your assumptions (including the new non-degenerate assumption),  gives a new function $g(x,y)$ that satisfies your assumptions and is a  counter-example to your conjecture.  It is too long to write so perhaps you can ask it as a new question and I can try to type it up there.

Comment: Great, thanks! I have re-asked the question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3495365/does-the-composition-of-a-non-degenerate-random-variable-valued-function-with-it.